# For Loop in a Function for Counting Vowels in a User Inputted String

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop

I am attempting to run a for loop in a function that is designed to count the vowels in a user inputted string. However, the error "builtins: TypeError" keeps appearing. I have tried simply using the length of the string, using the len function, but the error simply won't go away, and the code is ultimately broken because of this. Is there a solution to this? [Screenshot of the code with the error message showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adXTN.png)

For instance, I first ask the user to input a string. It is then supposed to use the function, called in the print statement, to count the vowels in the user inputted string. Currently, when typing a string, such as Kay, it produces an error code on line 6 that states "for char in (string):" which is the beginning of the for loop. The purpose of this loop is to ensure all letters are being checked for vowels before the code quits. There is a proper indentation, indicated by the lack of error and the principles of computer science and programming. The user inputted portion, which states "string= input("Please enter a phrase. ")" defines the variable string, and is placed at the top of the code.

Comment: [Create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not a screenshot) in order to get good responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reworked version of your code.

```
mystr = input('Please enter a phrase:\n')

def countvowels(x):
    counter = 0
    for i in x.lower():
        if i in set('aeiou'):
            counter += 1
    return counter

print(countvowels(mystr))
```

**Explanation**

- Do not name variables after classes or built-in functions, e.g. use `counter` instead of `sum`.
- Use `x.lower()`. Notice the brackets afterwards, indicating you want to function to execute.
- `set('aeiou')` creates a set of vowels, i.e. `{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}`. Checking if a variable is efficient with O(1) complexity.
- `input()` by default returns a string, so there is no need to convert to `str` manually.

Comment: Please note that `count` *is* a class method.

Comment: @Prune, good point, though this doesn't conflict with my point which refers to class names :). That said, I will rename it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `string.lower` to `string.lower()`. `string.lower` references the functions. Put the letters in quotes. You don't have those variables defined.

A better version of the function:

```
def countvowels(x):
    return sum([1 for a in x if a in "AEIOUaeiou"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.

First, `lower` is a function, you have to call it by putting parentheses after it.

```
string = string.lower()
```

Your code is just setting `string` to the function itself, not running it and using the result.

Second, when you test whether the character is a vowel, you need to put quotes around them. Otherwise, you're trying to use variables named `a`, `e`, etc. which you've never defined.

```
if char == 'a' or char == 'e' or char == 'i' or char == 'o' or char == 'u':
```

You could also simplify that to:

```
if char in 'aeiou':
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use "in" here:

```
string = raw_input('Please enter a phrase. ')
def countvowels(string):
  string = str(string).lower()
  sum = 0
  for char in string:
    if char in ('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'):
      sum += 1
  print(sum)
  return sum


countvowels(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

My own spin. Uses collections which is more efficient. Useful if you're parsing an entire book

```
from collections import Counter

user_input = input("Please enter a string: ")

# counter occurances of each letter
counter = Counter(user_input)

# drop non vowels
vowels_only = {k : v for k, v in counter.items() if k in "aeiou"}

# sum
vowels_total = sum(vowels_only.values())

print("Total vowels:", vowels_total)
```

### Quick solution

Here is a simple, though non-pythonic (messy) solution

```
user_input = input("Please enter a string: ")

# filter out everything that isn't a vowel, then count the len of what's left
vowel_count = len(list(filter(lambda x: x in "aeiou", list(user_input))))

print(vowel_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression

```
import re

mystrings = input("Please enter a string: ")

vowels = [len(re.findall('a|e|i|o|u', x.lower())) for x in mystrings]

print sum(vowels)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(userString.count(c) for c in 'aeiouAEIOU')
```

As a string, userString has its own 'count' method. Not sure this is ver performant though.